# Row id changing with addJSONdata in jqgrid

Tags: php, ajax, jqgrid

i load data to jqgrid with datatype jsonstring through a stored data. After first load i send a request on scroll via ajax post. in success i add data using

```
var jsongrid = eval(data);                  
 var thegrid = $("#Grid")[0];                       
 thegrid.addJSONData(jsongrid);
```

it adds data to my grid, but sorting is done only with the first data that created my grid. 
when adding through this way grid row id changed to a prefix 'jqq'. How can i make my row id with the id of each record

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            colNames:['id', 'aaa','bbb','ccc', 'ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh'],
            colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', hidden:true},
                    {name:'aa',index:'aa', width:200, align:'left', sorttype: 'string', sortable:true, resizable:false},
                    {name:'bb',index:'bb', width:150, align:'left', sorttype: 'string', sortable:true, resizable:false},
                    {name:'cc',index:'cc',width:90,align:"center", resizable:false, sorttype: 'int', sortable:true},
                    {name:'dd',index:'dd', hidden:true},
                    {name:'ee',index:'dd', width:100, align:'left', sorttype: 'string', sortable:true, resizable:false},        
                    {name:'ff',index:'ee', width:90, align:"center", sorttype: 'string', sortable:true, resizable:false},
                    {name:'gg',index:'gg', hidden:true},
                    {name:'hh',index:'hh', hidden:true},

            ],
            height:'530px',
            autowidth: true,
            scroll: true,
            pager: $('#myGridPager'),
            ignoreCase: true,
            //sortorder: "asc",
            gridview:true,
            loadtext: "Loading",
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadonce: false,
            loadui: 'enable',
            caption:"grid",
            datastr: $this->data,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
            },
            loadComplete:function(){
            },
            onPaging: function(pageButton){

                }
            },
            gridComplete: function(){
                initscroll();
                lastDiv = $("#myGrid").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:last").attr('id');
                celValue = $("#myGrid").jqGrid ('getCell', lastDiv, 'feedCurrentTime');
                newsTimeGrid = celValue;
               // alert(newsTimeGrid);
                $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#F4F4F4");
                }
        });
```

on scroll i call ajax using initscroll();

Comment: You should include **more details** about what you do and at least two rows of input data. In general it seems to me that you have chosen wrong (or at least not the best way). There are very few situations where you really need to use `addJSONData`. 99% cases of the usage `addJSONData` should be replaced with other constructions. By the way if you need to convert JSON string to data you should **never** use `eval` which can execute the code. Instead of that one should use `jQuery.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse`. If the rowids starts with `jqg` it means typically wrong input data which have no `id`.

Comment: You should post should comment to inform that you changed the text of the question. If you just change the code nobody get any notification about it. About your code: could you include an example of `datastr` which you use? I recommend you don't use `scroll: true` (virtual scrolling) because of a lot of restrictions and possible problems. Instead of that just use simple pager (for example add `toppager: true` option). You can change to virtual scrolling after having working solution.

Comment: It's important to know:  How many rows of data have you totally in the dataset which you want to display in jqGrid? (100, 1000, 10000, 10000000, ... ?) The solution could be heavy depend from the answer on the question. Moreover, you wrote about the usage of `addJSONData` method in your question, but the code which you posted don't contain it. Do you changed your concept?

Comment: can we implement client side sort with out using loadonce : true?

Comment: could you answer on the questions which I asked you before (see questions after "It's important to know:" or search for "?" in previous comments)?

Comment: iam planning to show 25 at a time, total will be 1000

Comment: I use addJSONData on init function..

Comment: Sorry, but I see no sense in `addJSONData`. Sorting of 1000 rows locally works *more quickly* as any request to the server because or the overhead of any network request. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/performane-1000.htm) which display 1000 rows without any paging (the slowest way). See [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/performane-90000_.htm) with 90000 rows and 20 rows per page. The last demos display loading time of grid in ms.

Comment: yes, i got it, my problem now is i have to sort data on client side. But when i use loadonce : true, it only take first 25, if loadonce is false it give correct result, but cannot perform sort

Comment: i trying to implement progressive loading of data and clientside sorting

Comment: it is not loading another set to the grid when using loadonce: true

Comment: If you use `loadonce: true` the the server should return **all data at once**. The `page`, `records` and `total` parts of the response will be ignored. So it's better to return the data in the array format: `[[{id:1,…}, {id:2,…}, {id:3,…}, ...{id:1234, ...}]`. By the way you don't need to have `{name:'id',index:'id', hidden:true}`. `id` will be saved as **attribute** of `<tr>`. No additional hidden column with `<td>` for `id` are required. You don't need create any other hidden columns. Instead of that you can use `getLocalRow` to get **full item of data** with all properties.

Comment: if loadonce: false, how can manage clientside sorting. every time when i click on column header it sends a request

Comment: now iam loading data with loadonce: false, it bind data to grid. i set scroll:1

Comment: It's seems that you don't understand full the meaning of `loadonce: false`. It means that **jqGrid should not hold any data locally** and to make every time requests to the server on sorting, paging and filtering/searching. `loadonce: false` means that **the server returns ALL data at once**, jqGrid saves the data in internal `data` and `_index` parameters and changes `datatype` to `"local"`. After that all sorting, paging and filtering/searching will be implemented locally without any requests to the server. The usage of client side sorting with `loadonce: false` have no sense.

Comment: ie when scroll: 1 and loadonce: true , how i can take next 25 from the server when scroller reach at the bottom

Comment: I wrote you before: **I recommend you don't use scroll: true (virtual scrolling) because of a lot of restrictions and possible problems.**, but it's your choice.

Comment: I wrote you before that all your described above constructs **are much slowly** as the simple `loadonce: true` scenario where you return all 1000 rows of data at once and sorting, paging and filtering will be made on the client side.

Comment: yes, i got that point..thanks for your kind reply..